# Как к проекту include exapt.h

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Пользуюсь wsl2 Ubuntu. Мне к библиотеке надо include файл exapt.h. Не могу понять, как его установить на компьютер, что можно было

```
include <exapt.h>
```

я пробовала

```bsh
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y expat
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло решение отсюда: https://github.com/scottcorgan/bucket-list/issues/2

Воспользовалась

```bsh
sudo apt-get install libexpat1-dev
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/631437)

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics в данном ответе есть решение